# PSR-0 auto-load testing problems

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, psr-0

I am fiddling around with autoloading, and trying to make a file structure that abides to the PSR-0 Standard. However I am getting this error:

`Warning: require(GetMatchHistory\api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php on line 15`

`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'GetMatchHistory\api.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php on line 15`

And here is my file structure:

[image: File structure]

I am using Test PHP with this autoloader function:

```
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');

$Query = new GetMatchHistory_api();
```

This function is copy-pasted from the suggested PSR-0 function [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

Am I misunderstanding with regards to how the structure should be? The class within "api.php" is `GetMatchHistory_api`

### Edit: Another problem

I have used the suggested answer by MrCode, however now I am having an issue where the autoloader wont load a class that is in another directory.

```
use Classes\Queries\History\GetMatchHistoryAPI;
use Classes\Queries\History\GetMatchHistoryBASE;
use Classes\Utilities\send;
```

When I am calling the `send` class, from within a function inside `GetMatchHistoryAPI`, I am receiving the error:

`Warning: require(Classes\Queries\History\send.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\Test.php on line 15`

However, as you can tell from the above image, the send class is not in that file path. Why is this error occurring?

Comment: You shouldn't require a file that doesn't exist. Still a fatal error then, but because the class isn't found, not because a failed require. Details, but more clear.

Comment: @Rudie I see that the file doesn't exist in that directory. However I am unsure as to why that is happening. If, as per the above code, I type `$Query = new send()`, the file is 'found' (sorry for poor terminology) in the correct location, but not when the `send` class is execute from another class.

Comment: I know. I wasn't actually commenting on the problem, sorry. The fatal error should be "Class X not found", not "Couldn't include file Y". Doesn't help you at all, but it's more 'correct'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that structure, you would need to rename the class to `Classes_Queries_GetMatchHistory_api` and change the code that instantiates it to:

```
$Query = new Classes_Queries_GetMatchHistory_api();
```

The reason for this is your `Test.php` resides at the root and the api class is in the directory `Classes/Queries/GetMatchHistory`.

---

Example using namespaces instead of the underscore method:

api.php:

```
namespace Classes\Queries\GetMatchHistory;

class api
{

}
```

Test.php:

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
$Query = new Classes\Queries\GetMatchHistory\api();
```

Or using `use`:

```
use Classes\Queries\GetMatchHistory\api;

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
$Query = new api();
```

---

To address your comment:

> I was going to have the same class names, but under a different folder (so GetMatchHistory - api.php and GetMatchDetails - api.php). I guess this would make it too ambiguous when calling the classes however

Namespaces are designed to solve this very problem. Namespaces allow you to have classes with the same name (but in different namespaces) and avoid any conflicts.

As an example, you have an `api` class under both `GetMatchHistory` and `GetMatchDetails`.

File: Classes/Queries/GetMatchHistory/api.php

```
namespace Classes\Queries\GetMatchHistory;

class api
{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'this is the GetMatchHistory api';
    }
}
```

File: Classes/Queries/GetMatchDetails/api.php

```
namespace Classes\Queries\GetMatchDetails;

class api
{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'this is the GetMatchDetails api, I am separate to the other!';
    }
}
```

File: Test.php (usage example)

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload');

$historyApi = new Classes\Queries\GetMatchHistory\api();
$detailsApi = new Classes\Queries\GetMatchDetails\api();
```

If you like, you can give an alias instead of typing out the whole fully qualified namespace:

```
use Classes\Queries\GetMatchHistory\api as HistoryApi;
use Classes\Queries\GetMatchDetails\api as DetailsApi;

$historyApi = new HistoryApi();
$detailsApi = new DetailsApi();
```

As you can see, namespaces make it possible to have multiple different classes with the same name, without having conflicts or making it ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this topic is still very confusing for me. 

Where I have the `api.php`, `base.php` and `db.php`, I was going to have the same class names, but under a different folder (so GetMatchHistory - api.php and GetMatchDetails - api.php). I guess this would make it too ambiguous when calling the classes however.

Comment: Additionally, another problem has come up for me, if you have a chance I'd value your input!

Comment: See my edit to address your comment about same class names (couldn't fit it in here). About your `send` error, can you show how you intantiate the class in Test.php? also show the content of `send.php` so I can see the classname and namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! With regards to the send part, [Here](http://pastebin.com/DHqEpfmU) is the contents of the Test.php, and [Here](http://pastebin.com/7vCdrJA7) is the contents of the send.php

For additional info, this line is what's used inside GetMatchHistoryAPI to initiate the send class:

`$request = new send(self::steamurl, $this->_get_data_query());`

Comment: Because you're using the send class inside GetMatchHistoryAPI, you need to either: 1. use the full namespace (inc root backslash) for example `$request = new \Classes\Utilities\send(self::steamurl, $this->_get_data_query());` or 2. inside `api.php` have `use \Classes\Utilities\send;` and you can keep your existing code as is.

Comment: Thank you very much. That sorted it! This seems a little cumbersome, but I guess I am doing this method of autoload correct?